# adding items to listview without multi-condition case in c#

Tags: c#, listview, registry, conditional-statements

I wrote a program to sort "all Windows installed software" in a ListView and I use below code in order to get list of all installed software.

```
string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
    {
        foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] row = { sk.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString()};
                    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
                    lstDisplayHardware.Items.Add(listViewItem);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
        }
        label1.Text += " (" + lstDisplayHardware.Items.Count.ToString() + ")";
    }
```

**note:** this code show me all installed programs which there are about **145** cases.

After that I decided to sort program size near it name so I changed line 6 as follows:

```
string[] row = { sk.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString() , sk.GetValue("EstimatedSize").ToString() };
```

Now the problem is the count of new result which are **94** cases. when i use this new code my program just show the results that have both `DisplayName & EstimatedSize` but because some programs haven't `EstimatedSize` property so they omitted from results and my count of result reduces from 145 to 96. What can I do?

Comment: For the programs which do not have EstimatedSize property, your execution is going in catch condition. That's why you are getting less count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fdf576x1.aspx) states

> Returns null if the name/value pair does not exist in the registry

Thus, you should check for nulls first.

```
var displayName = sk.GetValue("DisplayName");
var size = sk.GetValue("EstimatedSize");

ListViewItem item;
if(displayName != null)
{
    if(size != null)
         item = new ListViewItem(new string [] {displayName.ToString(), 
                                                       size.ToString()});
    else
         item = new ListViewItem(new string [] {displayName.ToString()});
    lstDisplayHardware.Items.Add(item);
}
```

---

if you need to check multiple properties.. as per your comment I would suggest something similar to this

```
var stringsToCheck  = new string [] { "DisplayName", "SomethingElse", 
                                      "AndSomethingElse" };
List<string> items = new List<string>();

foreach(var s in stringsToCheck)
{
     var val = sk.GetValue(s);
     if(val != null)
         items.Add(val.ToString());
}
var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(items.ToArray());
```

Note: the `ToArray` may not be needed.

Comment: this methode is too hard for longer modes like this:  sk.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString() , sk.GetValue("DisplayVersion").ToString(), sk.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString(), sk.GetValue("Publisher").ToString(), sk.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString(), sk.GetValue("Version").ToString(), sk.GetValue("VersionMinor").ToString(), sk.GetValue("VersionMajor").ToString(),

Comment: This isn't too hard at all.. I've added something that may look cleaner, but error handling must be done.

Comment: thanks for your new reply. as you said "this isn't too hard at all" for your first method, i just said that your code can be heavy and a lot of if and condition for more strings. but both works and thanks :)